# erro de The `useMongoClient` option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x, please remove it

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tentei conectar ao banco usando essas configurações;

```
'use strict'

var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/ep', { useMongoClient: true })
        .then(() => {
                console.log('conexão realizada com sucesso')
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Ao tentar executar a aplicação para teste gerou esse erro;

```
 npm start

> ep@1.0.0 start C:\layout resposive\API\ep
> nodemon index.js

[nodemon] 1.17.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
WARNING: The `useMongoClient` option is no longer necessary in mongoose 5.x, please remove it.
    at handleUseMongoClient (C:\layout resposive\API\ep\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:506:17)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\layout resposive\API\ep\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:407:7)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\layout resposive\API\ep\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:208:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\layout resposive\API\ep\index.js:6:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
conexão realizada com sucesso
```

Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essa foi uma das mudanças da versão 4 para 5, [no manual da migração falam sobre isso](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/migrating_to_5.md#connection-logic-and-usemongoclient). Basicamente: a partir da versão 5 essa opção foi removida, o valor é sempre `true`, daí que seja agora um erro passar essa opção de configuração.